# With the help of Chinese remainder theorem show that $ x^{144} \equiv 1 \pmod{ 323}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

With the help of Chinese remainder theorem show that $ x^{144} \equiv 1 \pmod{323}$ for all $x$ relatively prime to 323.

The problem with me is that I used to use CRT when $x$ is raised to a power of 1, but how can I work with $x$ to the power of 144, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $323=17\times 19$.  Solve the problem modulo $17, 19$ and use the CRT to get back to $323$.

Comment: What about the power 144, how can I deal with it ? @lulu

Comment: $17$ and $19$ are co-prime, so if $y\equiv 1  \mod 17$ and $y\equiv 1 \mod 19$ then $y\equiv 1 \mod (17\cdot 19).$

Comment: What is y ?@DanielWainfleet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$323=17 \cdot 19$, and by Fermat's Little Theorem:
$x^{144}=(x^{18})^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$
$x^{144}=(x^{16})^9 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$
For all $x$ coprime to $323$. Can you finish from here? It's a straightforward application of CRT.

Answer (score 3):

We have $323=324-1=18^2-1=17\times 19$.  So by CRT, it suffices to show
$x^{144}\equiv 1\pmod{17}$ and $x^{144}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$ for all $x$ coprime to 17 and 19.  Can you finish it from here?

Comment: What about the power 144, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

As $323=17\cdot 19$, so $x$ is coprime both to $17$ and $19$. By *lil' Fermat*, $x$ has order $16$ modulo $17$, and $18$ modulo $19$.

Therefore, it has order $\operatorname{lcm}(16,18)=144$ modulo $323$.

Comment: in fact if you wanted to, you could use the fact that 0 mod 16 and 0 mod 9 are coprime, and use CRT to get 0 mod 144 . being required.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

By Fermat’s little theorem, since $17$ and $19$ are prime, $x^{16}\equiv1\mod17$ and $x^{18}\equiv1\mod19.$

Use the constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem.